# How to make a GIF picture as a SplashScreen in an UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I want to use a GIF picture (with animation) as my Splash Screen in an UWP app. But I do not know how to achieve it. I find some link to give some solution but it seems they are not for UWP app. Like this one:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fe32aae-84cb-47fe-a2b0-6650ce22e25c/splashscreen-that-loads-an-animated-gif?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    

        String imgPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.ToString()) + "\\Ani.gif"; 

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html><body>");
        sb.Append("<img src = \"" + imgPath + "\">");
        sb.Append("</body></html>");

        webBrowser1.DocumentText = sb.ToString();

    }
```

Do you have workable solution for UWP app? Please advise. Thanks!

**More：**

By checking Mr. Zhu gives link, I make a gif Splash Screen and it works. But there is new issue: before the gif shows, there will be maybe 5s white screen. How to remove it?
The new test code is as below:

`Package.appxmanifest`: comment out the original splash screen png file

```
 <!--<uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />-->
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
            {
                bool loadState = (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
                ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash(e.SplashScreen, loadState);
                Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
            }

            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
```

ExtendedSplash.xaml：

```
<Page
x:Class="SplashScreenExample.ExtendedSplash"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SplashScreenExample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="#464646">
    <Image x:Name="extendedSplashImage" Source="Assets/test.gif"/>
</Grid>
```

ExtendedSplash.xaml.cs：

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace SplashScreenExample
{
    partial class ExtendedSplash : Page
    {
        internal Rect splashImageRect; // Rect to store splash screen image coordinates.
        private SplashScreen splash; // Variable to hold the splash screen object.
        internal bool dismissed = false; // Variable to track splash screen dismissal status.
        internal Frame rootFrame;

        // Define methods and constructor
        public ExtendedSplash(SplashScreen splashscreen, bool loadState)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;

            splash = splashscreen;
            if (splash != null)
            {
                // Register an event handler to be executed when the splash screen has been dismissed.
                splash.Dismissed += new TypedEventHandler<SplashScreen, Object>(DismissedEventHandler);

                // Retrieve the window coordinates of the splash screen image.
                splashImageRect = splash.ImageLocation;
                splashImageRect.Width = 1092;
                splashImageRect.Height = 1080;
                splashImageRect.X = 0;
                splashImageRect.Y = 0;
            }

            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context
            rootFrame = new Frame();
        }

        // Include code to be executed when the system has transitioned from the splash screen to the extended splash screen (application's first view).
        void DismissedEventHandler(SplashScreen sender, object e)
        {
            dismissed = true;

            // Complete app setup operations here...
        }

        void DismissExtendedSplash()
        {
            // Navigate to mainpage
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [**Display a splash screen for more time**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen)  that teach how to extend the splash, and you could custom the splash with Gif image. For complete code sample please check this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SplashScreen).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I checked your link and make a new demo, it works! But I met some new issue, which is updated in my main thread, please check it. Thanks!

Comment: The 5 seconds is default splash, please check if the default splash image path is correct, Please not you could not remove default splash.

Comment: I comment out the default splash screen png file in Package.appxmanifest. So you mean this step is hard coded so we cannot remove it?

Comment: Yep, the default splash could not be removed.

Comment: The better way is that make the default splash image same as your gif image and setting splash screen background bathed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You information is very useful!

Comment: It's my pleasure.